# Prompt user to choose the name and location when saving a pdf (python)

Tags: python, user-interface, pdf, tkinter

How can I change my code so I can save my final pdf (MergedFiles.pdf) with a name chosen by the user and in a location chosen by them. I would like to have a popup(maybe tkinter?) that will give the user the option of choosing the name and location to save the pdf file.

```
import PyPDF2 
 
# Open the files that have to be merged one by one
pdf1File = open(filepath, 'rb')
pdf2File = open('Summary_output.pdf', 'rb')
 
# Read the files that you have opened
pdf1Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf1File)
pdf2Reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf2File)
 
# Create a new PdfFileWriter object which represents a blank PDF document
pdfWriter = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the first document
for pageNum in range(pdf1Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf1Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
 
# Loop through all the pagenumbers for the second document
for pageNum in range(pdf2Reader.numPages):
    pageObj = pdf2Reader.getPage(pageNum)
    pdfWriter.addPage(pageObj)
 
# Now that you have copied all the pages in both the documents, write them into the a new document
pdfOutputFile = open('MergedFiles.pdf', 'wb')
pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
 
# Close all the files - Created as well as opened
pdfOutputFile.close()
pdf1File.close()
pdf2File.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a tkinter `filedialog`.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

pdfPath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = "*.pdf", filetypes = (("PDF Files", "*.pdf"),))
if pdfPath: #If the user didn't close the dialog window
    pdfOutputFile = open(pdfPath, 'wb')
    pdfWriter.write(pdfOutputFile)
    pdfOutputFile.close()
    pdf1File.close()
    pdf2File.close()
```

Firstly, it creates and hides a tkinter window. If you didn't do this an empty window would come up when you launched the file dialog. Then it uses `filedialog.asksaveasfilename` to launch the native OS file dialog. I've specified that it should ask for PDF files only. Then the if statement checks if a path has been returned, if it has it follows the same process as before.

Comment: perfect. Thank you so much!